# the difference between element_to_bytes() and element_snprint() in pbc library

Tags: c, pbcopy

I want to convert the pbc element_t to the human-friendly string. those two functions seems alike to satisfy the goal. however,I want to know the usage in detail about those. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking this up before coming here?

Comment: This you try [google](http://www.google.com) ?

Comment: I tried google "difference between element_to_bytes and element_snprint in pbc" before and got nothing, maybe it was stupid. I'll just split the two key words and search. Thanks you two.